# How did my market order not fill on TD webbroker?

Tags: market-order

I am upset at the fact that two MARKET orders I placed did not fill on TD webbroker. One to sell an existing asset (MNT.TO) and the second an order to buy (an ETF) with 16 million in volume that day.

Was I too late in the day ? 4:30 pm.

Was there no seller ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

The stock market closes at 4:00pm Eastern time. It was too late in the day.

The order may be good for tomorrow. You should check that.

Answer (score 2):

In the US, pre-market trading is from 4 am to 9:30 am EST and after hours trading is from 4 pm to 8 pm. on weekdays. Collectively this is called extended hours trading though some refer to both sessions as after hours trading.

Some brokers do not offer after hours trading. For those that do, it often requires that you get approval to do so, usually just a formality.

If your orders involved liquid securities, it's likely that either you don't have approval for after hours trading or that you didn't check the box that allows the order to be executed during extended hours trading.